# Source code security - working with companies iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, security, app-store-connect

I am currently working for a company on a rather big scale e-commerce project for iOS. Of course, they want to publish their project under their iTunes account. My concern is, all I want to do is to develop the project and upload the project in their behalf, from their account and keep my code to myself, just in case they want to do a similar project.

Will my ipa or code be safe? Any way they can reach the ipa or code only from the itunesconnect account ? Any thoughts and knowledge will be great from experienced developers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your client must use [Application Loader](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/apploader/ApplicationLoader_2.8.dmg)

- They have to give you an App Store provisionning profile
- Archive your app with "com.compagny.appname" with the provisionning profile
- Organizer should open after the process. Select your archive and click on Distribute button.
- Select Save for Enterprise or AdHoc Deployment
- Select the App Store provisionning profile
- Save your ipa on your disk (e.g Documents dir)
- Open terminal and go to Documents and execute : sudo chmod 755 yourApp.ipa
- Send your ipa to your client and that's all !

With this method your client won't get your code

Comment: Thanks for the detailed walk-through

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend having them add your developer account as a developer for them and having you upload it for them. This will reduce any possibility of any issues when you send them the IPA and they upload the file.

Once your IPA is created, they cannot retrieve the source code. They only thing they could do is get the images and the binary file. They could however reverse engineer the binary from assembly but that is VERY unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

Note that is this is an ecommerce application (handles credit cards) and in the US, PCI legal requirements would likely not allow them to have you upload anything, nor for that matter not have the source code. Their legal team should know this.

Comment: Thanks for the notice, I will be checking out for it

Comment: Our legal people are anal about PCI. I think the problem is whoever is the responsible party (collects the money) has to be auditable which means the source code has to be available and some kind of trail has to exist to ensure the application binary is doing only what they represent it as doing. Violating PCI can be a real headache :-)